# ng-model value not working when I used in Update Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

When i use this code in my controller. I think ng-model can output value based on input right ?

> ng-model = "$scope.title"

But when i implementation update data in my code. I'm confused because ng-model can output value but The value still output data.title even though I edited title input.

I edited this form in "tes1234" but the output still "tes"

[image]

Anybody to give me solution ? Thanks.

**UPDATED**

**This my HTML code :**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Title</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" ng-model="title">
</div>
</div>
```

**$scope.result grab data from API and then I use ng-repeat**

```
HttpService("POST", url, param, function(response){

            $scope.parsing = angular.fromJson(response.data);

            $scope.result = {};

            angular.forEach($scope.parsing, function(item){

                $scope.result[item._id] =  item;


            });
        });
```

**This is GetData() to grab data based on clicked and pass in my form**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in result">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{$index + 1}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ data._id }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ data.title }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ data.category.label }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ data.user.name }}
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getData(data)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

**This is GetData() to grab data based on clicked and pass in my form**

```
$scope.getData = function(data) {

    $scope.title = data.title;

}
```

**And this is my save after data updated**

```
$scope.Save = function() {
    var data = $.param({
           title : $scope.title,
    });

    console.log(data);
};
```

**Data Object Based From API**

```
{
    "status": "200",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "589c0484a6551f948e1d6914",
            "parent_id": 0,
            "parent_source": 0,
            "category_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347371",
            "user_id": "58942d43a6551fd7123bdcb1",
            "active": 1,
            "status": 1,
            "title": "coba tes",
            "description": "coba tes",
            "url": "coba-tes_6llapm",
            "extra": "EXTRA",
            "responded": "2017-02-09 12:56:20",
            "level": 0,
            "editor_pick": 0,
            "up_vote": 0,
            "down_vote": 0,
            "revision": 0,
            "answer_count": 2,
            "updated_at": "2017-02-09 13:04:14",
            "created_at": "2017-02-09 12:56:20",
            "tags": [],
            "user": {
                "_id": "58942d43a6551fd7123bdcb1",
                "status": 1,
                "username": "asdasdad",
                "email": "asdasdasd@gmail.com",
                "image": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/16299070_1114043338706757_6701359761657365227_n.jpg?oh=7ed22de2d576dc9d3cfd6a89aa386153&oe=5942BC1F",
                "about": "ini saya, saya suka makan dan belanja",
                "ref_id": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1104332756344482/",
                "name": "asdasd",
                "login_ip": "192.168.100.4",
                "notif_check": "2017-02-03 14:12:03",
                "token": "$2y$10$EMGp1wWnnPUDRJ/dSybCIeei88jROcAqsAsgXri2l8j/H8FMSt5iS",
                "updated_at": "2017-02-10 10:52:33",
                "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:12:03"
            },
            "category": {
                "_id": "58942caba6551fd2c3347371",
                "label": "My Kids and I",
                "active": 1,
                "url": "my-kids-and-i",
                "parent_id": 0,
                "level": 0,
                "dfp_interest": "[]",
                "meta_title": "",
                "meta_description": "",
                "meta_keyword": "",
                "updated_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31",
                "created_at": "2017-02-03 14:09:31"
            }
        }]
}
```

Comment: sorry but why you do a $scope.getData ? ..to retrive the value of title?? .. it is not necessary .. title is always binded (in real time) with the value setted in the textbox

Comment: why you don't just do ...  $scope.Save = function() {
    var data = {
           title : $scope.title,
    };

    console.log(data);
};

Comment: which **data** you mean by `ng-click="getData(data)"`

Comment: Yes, $scope.getData to retrive the value of title. Im used that because to fill my form. I need to Update Data

Comment: data from "<ng-repeat="data in result">" and result I retrive from API

Comment: Pass model object as an argument to the `getData(title)`. So i will take the latest value of title.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `var data = $.param...` to `$scope.data=$.param...`.

Comment: Please console log `data` value  that you pass to `$scope.data` function and see what it logs

Comment: the value is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I have added demo.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.result = {
    "status": "200",
    "data": [{
      "_id": "589c0484a6551f948e1d6914",
      "parent_id": 0,
      "title": "coba tes",
    }]
  }



  $scope.getData = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.title = data.title;

  };
  $scope.save = function() {
    console.log($scope.title);
    $scope.title;

  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" ng-model="title">
    </div>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in result.data">
      <td>
        {{$index + 1}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ data._id }}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{ data.title}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ data.category.label }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ data.user.name }}
      </td>
      <td width="20%">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="getData(data)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Save</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Not working and showing "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: Yes, your code success to grab value based clicked but I mean when the value I change , the output still based clicked. My expected is when i change value, the output is change too

Comment: OMG, im confused. your code is same with me but your code is working. My code is not working

Answer (score 0):

change the getDate Function like this

```
$scope.getData = function(data) {
    $scope.title = data[0].title;
 }
```